# Report in Dynamics CRM 2011 on IE 11

Tags: report, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, compatibility, internet-explorer-11

I just upgraded to IE 11, inserted my CRM URL in the compatibility view settings and everything seems fine but when I run a report (correctly shown on IE 10) it is empty.

I know that IE 11 is not supported yet, but do anyone know any workaround different from downgrade to IE10?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this in both CRM online/on-premise and Win7/8/8.1. In each instance I have been able to resolve the issue by:

1. Adding the 2nd level domain to compatibility view setting AND
2. Adding the 2nd level domain to my trusted sites (e.g. "*.dynamics.com" for CRM on-line).This has especially helped for users on Win 8.